# java.sql.SQLException: near ".": syntax error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I've found the SQL I searched to Update some fields but I got the error of the title:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.json = 'ex', a.last_save = 'ex', a.carte = 'ex'
FROM partie_l AS a
INNER JOIN carte AS b
ON a.start_carte = b.hash
WHERE b.json = 'ex' AND a.start_joueurs = 'ex' AND a.param = 'ex'
```

I've replaced my data with ex, else it would be too long.

Here is the structure of my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE "carte" ("hash" TEXT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,"json" TEXT NOT NULL ,"nb_jrs" INTEGER,"preview" BLOB, "creator" TEXT DEFAULT atoll, "name" TEXT, "tetra" BOOL)

CREATE TABLE "partie_l" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,"json" TEXT,"create" DATETIME,"last_save" DATETIME,"start_carte" TEXT,"preview" BLOB,"param" TEXT,"start_joueurs" TEXT,"carte" TEXT, "name" TEXT)
```

Edit: Sqlite doesn't support inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using the table alias for the table to be updated.

```
UPDATE partie_l 
SET json = 'ex', 
    last_save = 'ex',
    carte = 'ex' 
FROM partie_l 
    INNER JOIN carte AS b 
    ON partie_l.start_carte = b.hash 
WHERE b.json = 'ex' AND partie_l.start_joueurs = 'ex' AND partie_l.param = 'ex'
```

For SQLite try

```
UPDATE partie_l 
SET json = 'ex', 
    last_save = 'ex',
    carte = 'ex' 
WHERE partie_l.start_joueurs = 'ex' 
AND partie_l.param = 'ex' 
AND partie_l.start_carte IN (SELECT hash FROM carte WHERE json='ex')
```

Comment: Please highlight and/or summarize the difference(s) and explain why they are of importance.

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using?

Comment: Ok, that was my fault. I didn't know that sqlite didn't supported inner join. Thanx for your help